# Zend Framework 2 get params from a string or current url

Tags: zend-framework2, url-routing, zend-route

I need to get the params from the current url, but i'm getting an error when i put my code in *public function __construct*

Here's my current code:

```
class BlogController extends AbstractActionController{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //echo $this->params()->fromRoute('controller');
        //echo $this->params()->fromRoute('action');
    }
}
```

if there's a way to get params from a string/current url. It will be fine.

please help. i need this for my ACL so that i will not check in every function what is the current action and controller.

Comment: You can't do this in the constructor - why do you specifically need it there?

Comment: i need to put it on the constructor so that before the page load ' will know what controller or what action that the user is accessing. i also need to put it on the constructor so that when i have a new module.. it will not be necessary to put my code in every function inside the controller..

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `params()` controller plugin provides parameters from five different sources:

- $this->params()->fromRoute() - Parameters you defined in routing configuration
- $this->params()->fromFiles() - Attached files in request
- $this->params()->fromHeader() - HTTP header parameters.
- $this->params()->fromPost() - POST parameters
- $this->params()->fromQuery() - Query parameters.

So, what you need is `fromQuery()`, not `fromRoute()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer,, i tried fromQuery(); but it returns an empty array(). Here's my code: echo '</pre>'; print_r($this->params()->fromQuery()); echo '</pre>';

Comment: Hmm, what is the output of the `var_dump($_GET);`? Did you pass querystring parameters properly in http (nginx/apache) level?

Comment: var_dump($_GET) returns array(0) { }

Comment: Please also check Tim's comment under the question. __construct() may not correct place to do that.

Comment: Please provide more info about what u trying to accomplish. var_dump($_GET) must give you an array of url parameters only if the cuurent page url from your browser has it;
If it from variable string do different approach

Comment: Please paste your page url from your browser

Answer (score 0):

now i know that its not posible.

I found an answer in some docu then i add this code to my Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
        $this->initAcl($e);
        $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach('route', array($this, 'checkAcl'));
}

public function initAcl(MvcEvent $e) {

    $acl = new \Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl();
    $roles = array(
        'guest'=> array( //functions that the user can access
            'registration',
            'home',
        ),
        'admin'=> array(
            'registration',
        ),
    );
    $allResources = array();
    foreach ($roles as $role => $resources) {

        $role = new \Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\GenericRole($role);
        $acl->addRole($role);

        $allResources = array_merge($resources, $allResources);

        //adding resources
        foreach ($resources as $resource) {

             if(!$acl->hasResource($resource))
                $acl->addResource(new \Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\GenericResource($resource));
        }
        //adding restrictions
        foreach ($resources as $resource) {
            $acl->allow($role, $resource);
        }
    }
    $e->getViewModel()->acl = $acl;
}

public function checkAcl(MvcEvent $e) {
        $route = $e -> getRouteMatch() -> getMatchedRouteName();
        //you set your role
        $userRole = 'guest';

        //if (!$e -> getViewModel() -> acl -> isAllowed($userRole, $route)) {
        if ($e -> getViewModel()->acl->hasResource($route) && !$e->getViewModel()->acl->isAllowed($userRole, $route)) { 
            $response = $e -> getResponse();
            //location to page or what ever
            $response -> getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $e -> getRequest() -> getBaseUrl() . '/404');
            $response -> setStatusCode(404);

        }
}
```